# Remove refs/original/heads/master from git repo after filter-branch --tree-filter?

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history, git-plumbing

I had the same question as asked here: [New git repository in root directory to subsume an exist repository in a sub-directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193507/new-git-repository-in-root-directory-to-subsume-an-exist-repository-in-a-sub-dire)

I followed this answer here: [New git repository in root directory to subsume an exist repository in a sub-directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193507/new-git-repository-in-root-directory-to-subsume-an-exist-repository-in-a-sub-dire/7194124#7194124)

Now, `gitk --all` shows two histories: one culminating in the current `master`, and one named `original/refs/heads/master`.

I don't know what this second history is, or how to remove it from the repo. I don't need two histories in my repository.

How do I get rid of it?

To reproduce yourself:

```
mkdir -p project-root/path/to/module
cd project-root/path/to/module
mkdir dir1 dir2 dir3 
for dir in * ; do touch $dir/source-file-$dir.py ; done
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'Initial commit'
```

Now we have the original poster's problem. Let's move the root of the git repo to project-root using the answer linked above:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'mkdir -p path/to/module ; git mv dir1 dir2 dir3 path/to/module' HEAD
rm -rf path
cd ../../../ # Now PWD is project-root
mv path/to/module/.git .
git reset --hard
```

Now, see my current problem:

```
gitk --all &
git show-ref
```

How do I get rid of `refs/original/heads/master` and all associated history?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete the old history after running git filter-branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984428/how-to-delete-the-old-history-after-running-git-filter-branch)

Answer (score 368, accepted):

`refs/original/*` is there as a backup, in case you mess up your filter-branch. Believe me, it's a *really* good idea.

Once you've inspected the results, and you're very confident that you have what you want, you can remove the backed up ref:

```
git update-ref -d refs/original/refs/heads/master
```

or if you did this to many refs, and you want to wipe it all out:

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/original/ | xargs -n 1 git update-ref -d
```

(That's taken directly from the filter-branch manpage.)

This doesn't apply to you, but to others who may find this: If you do a filter-branch which *removes* content taking up significant disk space, you might also want to run `git reflog expire --expire=now --all` and `git gc --prune=now` to expire your reflogs and delete the now-unused objects. (Warning: completely, totally irreversible. Be very sure before you do it.)

Comment: After doing update-ref, reflog expire and gc, both of these files still reference the original ref: .git/info/refs and .git/packed-refs

Looks like maybe that should say this instead: `git update-ref -d refs/original/refs/heads/master`

Comment: I guess you accidentally mixed the words: If I am right, it should be `git update-ref -d original/refs/heads/master`? However, only your second command worked for me.

Comment: It’s `git update-ref -d refs/original/refs/heads/master` btw. You can see the full name using `git show-ref`.

Comment: What about the shorter `git show-ref refs/original/* --hash | xargs -n 1 git update-ref -d`?

Comment: using gitextensions there is View > Show reflog commits, which totally obviates this backup; you always have a clearly visible backup whatever you do in git this way.

Answer (score 11):

And if you're in Windows PowerShell:

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/original/ | foreach-object -process { git update-ref -d $_ }
```

Answer (score 10):

`filter-branch` keeps backups so repository need to clean up reflogs and garbage collect. Make sure that have no need in this backups before deletion:

```
rm -Rf .git/refs/original
git gc --aggressive --prune=now
```