# Git: How to remove file from historical commit?

Tags: git

I have a commit with the ID `56f06019`, for example. In that commit I have accidentally committed large file (50 MB). In another commit I added the same file but in the right size (small). Now my repo is too heavy when I clone. How do I remove that large file from the repo history to reduce the size of my repo?

Comment: in my case, its not a large file, but a configuration file containing database credits. I was studying git, at that time I were unaware of .gitignore.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)

Comment: related https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/

Answer (score 220, accepted):

Chapter 9 of the [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book) book has a section on [Removing Objects](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery#Removing-Objects).

Let me outline the steps briefly here:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter \
    'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch path/to/mylarge_50mb_file' \
    --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Like the rebasing option described before, `filter-branch` is rewriting operation. If you have published history, you'll have to `--force` push the new refs.

The `filter-branch` approach is considerably more powerful than the `rebase` approach, since it

- allows you to work on all branches/refs at once,
- renames any tags on the fly
- operates cleanly even if there have been several merge commits since the addition of the file
- operates cleanly even if the file was (re)added/removed several times in the history of (a) branch(es)
- doesn't create new, unrelated commits, but rather copies them while modifying the trees associated with them. This means that stuff like signed commits, commit notes etc. are preserved

`filter-branch` keeps backups too, so the size of the repo won't decrease immediately unless you expire the reflogs and garbage collect:

```
rm -Rf .git/refs/original       # careful
git gc --aggressive --prune=now # danger
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this doesn't seem to work under windows cmd.exe. Seems to work under cygwin fine, though.

Comment: I got the above git filter-branch to work by using double-quotes instead of single-quotes (on Windows Server 2012 cmd.exe)

Comment: What worked for me was this filter-branch command line.

 `git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --ignore-unmatch --cached PathTo/MyFile/ToRemove.dll' -- fbf28b005^..`  
Then
`rm --recursive --force .git/refs/original` and `rm --recursive --force .git/logs`

Then I used the `git prune --expire now` 
and `git gc --aggressive`

This worked better for me than your exact steps listed above.  Thank you for including the link to the Git Pro book as it was invaluable.

Comment: After the filter-branch command, the only way I could get the size of the .git folder down was to follow the command found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904860/how-to-remove-unreferenced-blobs-from-my-git-repo

    git -c gc.reflogExpire=0 -c gc.reflogExpireUnreachable=0 -c     gc.rerereresolved=0 \
    -c gc.rerereunresolved=0 -c gc.pruneExpire=now gc "$@"

Comment: For shrinking the repo, I used the commands listed in git filter-branch doc : https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#_checklist_for_shrinking_a_repository

Comment: @TannerBabcock with that amount of detail nobody is going to be able to help. The book is well known, it helped enough people facing the same problems, so I bet there's just an error with expectations. Why don't you just ask for help with your situation, instead of unproductively complaining at existing posts? We're all here to help

Comment: For me, this worked exactly as posted by Matthew. The only thing I had to change was the filename.

Comment: @jollycat Glad to hear!

Comment: This worked for me but I then got a "unrelated histories" error when trying to pull before I pushed. I solved this by git pull --allow-unrelated-histories

Comment: @user7722867 Be careful. That's not "solving" the fact that histories are unrelated - it merely silences the warning. The thing about rebasing is that it rewrites your history. You will need to rebase all branches onto this rewrite so that you can have normal branch/merge, Otherwise it can be useful to have "unrelated" branches only if you intend to (a) keep independent branches that never interact (b) keep unrelated branches for purposes of e.g. cherry-picking individual commits.

Comment: Well, I tried this on my repo where I had hundreds of images, and somehow it actually increased the size by about double! I followed the exact steps of this answer, hopefully the references in the comments will still solve it for me

Comment: @KoenduBuf It probably means you have to garbage collect. Git will do this periodically, but you can do this if you're SURE you don't need the now-rewritten commits in the old form. (It does make sense that a version control system tries not to lose your old data see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654822/remove-refs-original-heads-master-from-git-repo-after-filter-branch-tree-filte)

Comment: I did garbage collect, in about 200 ways, it did not solve the problem for me. Here is (simplified) what happened: I basically had 2 giant files, but only used the first first command on one of them, since I forgot I had a second giant file. Then die some garbage collection, which only increased the size of my stuff for some reason (maybe it stored the other giant file multiple times, idk?) all was solved when I removed the other giant file as well

Comment: oops, why to use --all flag? wanted to test on the test branch, didn't notice that

Comment: @AlexanderMyasnikov because usually files are being removed for important reasons (like, they're big or contain sensitive information). Unless you process all branches, the file will still be in the repository. Also, good thing that you still have the backup after `filter-branch`.

Answer (score 24):

You can use **git-extras** tool. The **obliterate** command completely remove a file from the repository, including past commits and tags.

https://github.com/tj/git-extras/blob/master/Commands.md

Comment: Awesome! This did the job. So beautifully simple.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a wonderful and simplest solution.

Comment: This had to rewrite the entire history which was about 30000 commits, even though the files I want to remove were just 5 commits old.

Comment: `git obliterate` does basically [the same](https://github.com/tj/git-extras/blob/6d73f74f83e734276b32e408f21214f489e812a3/bin/git-obliterate#L4) as the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8741530/1319821).

Answer (score 10):

I tried using the following answer on windows
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8741530/8461756

**Single quote does not work on windows; you need double-quotes.**

Following worked for me.

```sh
git filter-branch --force --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch PathRelativeRepositoryRoot/bigfile.csv" -- --all
```

After removing the big file, I was able to push my changes to GitHub master.

Comment: somehow `.\relative\path\to\file*` doesn't work for me. I need to use `*file*` instead

Comment: @Ooker the path you used, was it relative to repo root?

Comment: 2 years have passed and I have no idea what was then. But I suppose yes

Answer (score 1):

You will need to [git rebase](http://gitmanual.org/git-rebase.html) in the interactive mode see an example here: [How can I remove a commit on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448919/how-can-i-remove-a-commit-on-github) and [how to remove old commits](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~blynn/gitmagic/ch05.html#_8230_and_then_some).

If your commit is at HEAD minus 10 commits:

```
$ git rebase -i HEAD~10
```

After the edition of your history, you need to push the "new" history, you need to add the `+` to force (see the refspec in the [push options](http://gitmanual.org/git-push.html)):

```
$ git push origin +master
```

If other people have already cloned your repository, you will to inform them, because you just changed the history.

Comment: That does **not** remove the large file from history. Also, the canonical way to force push is `git push --force` or `git push -f` (which doesn't require people to know the branch push target)

Comment: Based on the question, the new file is exactly the same as the old file, that is, the same path. This is why you cannot directly use `git rm` on the path.

Comment: @sehe, if you do a rebase eliminating the commit with the huge file, it is gone for good.

Comment: @vonbrand only from that branch that you rebased. I'm not assuming the 'from' branch gets deleted. But yeah, if you delete a revision tree branch, that will help :_

Comment: @sehe, sure, you have to chase down all branches containing the offending commit. If it is before some bushiness in the repo, you'll have a lot of reorganizing to do. But rebase _is_ the tool for this.

Comment: mmm I guess in the context of a single commit, using rebase is as good, and probably easier to explain. My answer is just more general. Imagine a large binary file that changed over many commits over the years. You wouldn't want to be manually rebasing your way of there. @vonbrand Thanks for a fruitful discussion

Answer (score -1):

You can use a simple Command to deleted

```
 git rm -r -f app/unused.txt 
 git rm -r -f yourfilepath
```

Comment: This will leave the file in the history. The question is to remove the file from the history as well. So it was like the file was never added in the first place.