# Git removed file yet still is pushed

Tags: git, ruby-on-rails-4, github

I have a file that for some reason got installed in my project qt-linux-opensource-5.0.2-x86-offline.run. This file is super big so i removed it in git with:

```
git rm qt-linux-opensource-5.0.2-x86-offline.run
```

The problem is when i push the file still is trying to be pushed... how do I completely remove this file. I already deleted the file from my computer (didn't want it in that directory) and for extra protection I put it in my git ignore file. I need to update the app but this file is making it impossible thanks to it's 300mb+ size. Thanks to everyone who can help.

Comment: Did you ever push the commit that introduced this file?

Comment: Not yet, I have a few more commits (7 since last push) before I realized that this file was there.

Comment: Seems to be the same problem resolved here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740187/git-how-to-remove-file-from-historical-commit

Comment: The answer to that problem didn't solve mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already committed the file. Therefore, it's in your history, and `git rm` won't remove the file from it.

Luckily, you didn't push your commits yet, which enables you to use `git filter-branch`. The Git Pro book contains a [section on this command](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#The-Nuclear-Option:-filter-branch), and [filter-branch's documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) got the right example:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter \ 
 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch qt-linux-opensource-5.0.2-x86-offline.run' \
  origin/master..HEAD
```

However, make sure that you understand `filter-branch` before you use it. The book doesn't call it the "Nuclear option" just for fun.

(Also, consider adding `*.run` to your `.gitignore`)

Comment: I ran the filter branch command but the file still tries to push

Comment: That's strange. That `filter-branch` command should remove the file from any commit between `origin/master` and `HEAD`. Did you try `git rebase -i origin/master` and removing/editing the commit by hand?

Comment: Is their a way to remove by file and not commit? (I don't commit often and add alot of things at once)

Comment: Also I don't use branches so everything is on master

Comment: I tried the rebase thing and i found the commit from last push but it was automatically added back in (last commit was during a merge)

Comment: Wait. Was that a merge from `origin/master`? If that's the case, use `filter-branch ... HEAD` (without `origin/master`). However, it seems like the file was is already upstream from a previous commit.

Comment: I figured it out! I re-read the blog post and figured it out! I did:    git filter-branch --index-filter \ 
 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch qt-linux-opensource-5.0.2-x86-offline.run' \HEAD. thanks man : )

Comment: @Jakxna360: Which is what I meant by my last comment :D. Your commit was older than `origin/master`, therefore, it wasn't in `origin/master..HEAD`. Glad that I could help.