# Size of .git folder locally VS after clone

Tags: git, filesize, git-clone

I have a git repo, locally it was 3.9GB, cloning it freshly 3.3GB, it had some giant files in it, but I used https://stackoverflow.com/a/8741530/7857013 to remove them from git history.

Now locally my repo is 1.5GB, and cloning it freshly it is 80MB! The 1.5GB is in `./.git/objects`. How come it is still so big locally, and how do I fix it?

Quickly before anybody says 'local branches'. The repo has 1 branch, and never had more than that one main branch (locally or remote).

Comment: At the very end of the linked answer there is `git gc` command. Did you run it?

Comment: Yes I did run it

Answer (score 1):

> cloning it freshly it is 80MB

Then push every branch (just to be safe) and throw your whole folder away and do your fresh clone.

Comment: This is obviously a solution, but does not help anyone understand why the size is there

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904860/how-to-remove-unreferenced-blobs-from-my-git-repo

Answer (score 0):

Try with `git gc --aggressive`.

Let me known if it worked.

Comment: I did, ```git gc --aggressive --prune=now``` specifically, just like it says at the answer of the link in my question