# What causes this commit to still be referenced?

Tags: git

There's a huge binary commit I'd like to prune from my repo.

```
> git log --all -- '*.tiff'
commit 05f03aba18164c736182e612181f99ce04e38845
...
```

It's not part of a branch...

```
> git branch --all --contains 05f03aba
> (nothing)
```

..., it's not pointed to by a tag and it can't be referenced by the reflog. (I've cleared it with `git reflog expire --expire=now --all`)

Yet the commit is somehow referenced and therefore not pruned:

```
> git fsck --unreachable
> (nothing)
```

How can I find out what causes the commit to be referenced?

Comment: Your second command must be `git branch --all --contains xxx` (otherwise you'll miss remote-tracking branches). Also, you need to check the tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your commit is reached by `git log`, you can just run `git log --source` to show from where your commit was reached.

It might be referenced by a backup of `git filter-branch` – see this question for more detail: [Remove refs/original/heads/master from git repo after filter-branch --tree-filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654822/remove-refs-original-heads-master-from-git-repo-after-filter-branch-tree-filte)

Comment: Solved: `git log --source` revealed that the commit was in `refs/original/refs/heads/master`. After deleting the corresponding line from `repo/.git/packed-refs`, GC could remove the blob. Where did this `refs/original/refs/...` come from? How could I have deleted it with Git's command line tools?

Comment: `refs/original/refs/` is created by `git filter-branch`, as a backup. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654822/remove-refs-original-heads-master-from-git-repo-after-filter-branch-tree-filte

Comment: Extended the answer with these infos.

Comment: You can use `git update-ref -d` to delete the ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654822/remove-refs-original-heads-master-from-git-repo-after-filter-branch-tree-filte