# Create a submodule repository from a folder and keep its git commit history

Tags: git, git-submodules, revision-history

I have a web application that explores other web applications in a particular way. It contains some web demos in a `demos` folder and one of the demo should now have it's own repository. I would like to create a separate repository for this demo application and make it a <del>subpackage</del> [submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) from main repository without losing its commit history.

*Is it possible to keep the commit history from the files in a repository's folder and create a repository from it and use it as a [submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) instead?*

Comment: I ahve been searching how to move directory 1 from Git repository A to Git repository B. +1 for the link to the article.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514197/convert-a-git-folder-to-a-submodule-retrospectively

Comment: Yes this is indeed very similar, solutions differ a little, thanks for sharing this

Answer (score 240, accepted):

## Detailed Solution

> See the note at the end of this answer (last paragraph) for a quick alternative to git submodules using npm ;)

In the following answer, you will know how to extract a folder from a repository and make a git repository from it and then including it as a [submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) instead of a folder.

Inspired from Gerg Bayer's article [Moving Files from one Git Repository to Another, Preserving History](http://gbayer.com/development/moving-files-from-one-git-repository-to-another-preserving-history/)

At the beginning, we have something like this:

```
<git repository A>
    someFolders
    someFiles
    someLib <-- we want this to be a new repo and a git submodule!
        some files
```

In the steps below, I will refer this `someLib` as `<directory 1>`.

At the end, we will have something like this:

```
<git repository A>
    someFolders
    someFiles
    @submodule --> <git repository B>

<git repository B>
    someFolders
    someFiles
```

### Create a new git repository from a folder in an other repository

#### Step 1

Get a fresh copy of the repository to split.

```bash
git clone <git repository A url>
cd <git repository A directory>
```

#### Step 2

The current folder will be the new repository, so remove the current remote.

```bash
git remote rm origin
```

#### Step 3

Extract history of the desired folder and commit it

```bash
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter <directory 1> -- --all
```

You should now have a git repository with the files from `directory 1` in your repo's root with all related commit history.

#### Step 4

Create your online repository and push your new repository!

```bash
git remote add origin <git repository B url>
git push
```

You may need to set the `upstream` branch for your first push

```bash
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

### Clean `<git repository A>` (optional, see comments)

We want to delete traces (files and commit history) of `<git repository B>` from `<git repository A>` so history for this folder is only there once.

This is based on [Removing sensitive data](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data) from github.

Go to a new folder and

```bash
git clone <git repository A url>
cd <git repository A directory>
git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch <directory 1> -r' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Replace `<directory 1>` by the folder you want to remove. `-r` will do it recursively inside the specified directory :). Now push to `origin/master` with `--force`

```bash
git push origin master --force
```

### Boss Stage (See Note below)

Create a [submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) from `<git repository B>` into `<git repository A>`

```bash
git submodule add <git repository B url>
git submodule update
git commit
```

Verify if everything worked as expected and `push`

```bash
git push origin master
```

#### Note

After doing all of this, I realized in my case that it was more appropriate to use [npm](https://npmjs.org/) to manage my own dependencies instead. We can specify git urls and versions, see the [package.json git urls as dependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies).

If you do it this way, the repository you want to use as a requirement must be an **npm module** so it must contain a `package.json` file or you'll get this error: `Error: ENOENT, open 'tmp.tgz-unpack/package.json'`.

## tldr (alternative solution)

You may find it easier to use [npm](https://npmjs.org/) and [manage dependencies with git urls](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies):

- Move folder to a new repository
- run `npm init` inside both repositories
- run `npm install --save git://github.com/user/project.git#commit-ish` where you want your dependencies installed

Comment: Step "Clean <git repository A>" should be avoided. Doing this you cannot fully restore/checkout older versions/commits from your history.

You should just git rm the folder and add the submodule. So you ensure to have a fully working copy when checking out older commits.

Comment: Shouldn't you do `cd someLib` before Step 2? You say "The current folder will be the new repository" but actually it will not; the new repository (submodule) is *inside* that folder.

Comment: Not exactly, as `someLib` is actually `<directory 1>`, next commands passes `<directory 1>` when desired

Comment: confirming: yes, it works for more than one submodule. Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. Also, didn't have to use npm.

Comment: Glad to see it helped and yes indeed, extracting everything into more than one submodules shouldn't be much different. npm was more a personal suggestion as it turned out to be easier to use for my team at the time, I did extract history but used npm instead of submodules.

Comment: I would add [information](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7654880/1218980) about the `refs/original/...` which is created at step 3.

Comment: Could be a git-lfs issue, where are you stuck? Any error?

Comment: GitHub made an article on how to achieve the extraction of a folder into a new repository:

https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/

Comment: is there an easy or common way how to handle the outsourced folder if it's in a sub-path and not directly in root? Question is related to the new repo but primary to the old one where the new one has to be loaded now.

Comment: @David I'm not sure what you mean by _outsourced folder_, but the solutions shared above should apply to no matter where the folders are. Just input the relative path to each of them each time. The `<git repository A directory>` can be a directory in a directory.

Comment: By the way, this question relates to a similar problem: converting a folder into a dependency. Maybe you should stick with the tools that comes with your programming language to solve this. I've added an alternative solution with `npm`, but I'd suggest having a look at how this can be done with your language's package manager.

Comment: Thanks @GabLeRoux I used your description already twice for a PHP-project and it was working quite well. The only problem is how to configure that the subrepository is loaded then in the correct sub-directory (hope with these words it's clearer than in my question). I've to adjust one and create another composer.json-file, so probably I've to configure it there.

Comment: Just for git I thought there is perhaps a way 'to tell' git that the sub-repository never should be loaded in the root of the parent too. I know for cli there exists the option to assign a directory as parameter but that has to be entered each time and be known by every user. Is there perhaps the option to configure it for git permanent?

Answer (score 13):

The solution by @GabLeRoux squashes the branches, and the related commits.

A simple way to clone and keep all those extra branches and commits:

1 - Make sure you have this git alias

```
git config --global alias.clone-branches '! git branch -a | sed -n "/\/HEAD /d; /\/master$/d; /remotes/p;" | xargs -L1 git checkout -t'
```

2 - Clone the remote, pull all branches, change the remote, filter your directory, push

```
git clone git@github.com:user/existing-repo.git new-repo
cd new-repo
git clone-branches
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin git@github.com:user/new-repo.git
git remote -v
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter my_directory/ -- --all
git push --all
git push --tags
```

Comment: it works fine, except LFS (see answer from ls below) and also Tags: in my case, it recreated whole parent directory in new repository, as tags were created for the whole parent directory. I don't need that

Answer (score 7):

GabLeRoux's solution works well except if you use `git lfs` and have large files under the directory you want to detach. In that case, after step 3 all the large files will remain to be pointer files instead of real files. I guess it's probably due to the `.gitattributes` file being removed in the filter branch process.

Realizing this, I found the following solution works for me:

```
cp .gitattributes .git/info/attributes
```

Copying `.gitattributes` which git lfs uses to track large files to `.git/` directory to avoid being deleted.

When filter-branch is done don't forget to put back the `.gitattributes` if you still want to use git lfs for the new repository:

```
mv .git/info/attributes .gitattributes
git add .gitattributes
git commit -m 'added back .gitattributes'
```

Comment: very useful, hard to find!

Answer (score 2):

`filter-branch` has been superceded by `filter-repo`.

The procedure for splitting a subfolder out using `filter-repo` is documented here:

https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/using-git/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository

In step 3 of [GabLeRoux's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18129693/278403) use:

```
git filter-repo --path FOLDER-NAME/
```