# Git: Moving files into an existing submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

How do I move files and folders in my master repo into an existing submodule?  Can I preserve history somehow?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a submodule repository from a folder and keep its git commit history](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17413493/create-a-submodule-repository-from-a-folder-and-keep-its-git-commit-history)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have only a single branch in you repos: take your submodule repo, add your master repo as a second remote, fetch the history and remove everything but the chosen files. merge the result to you master repository branch.

Here "remove" could mean two things. Either a simple `git rm` which will create a clean HEAD but the deleted files will remain in history. Or a `git filter-branch` which is able to create a new history consisting only of the chosen files.

At your master repository you have basically the same options. Either use `git rm` to delete the moved files in HEAD or use `git filter-branch` to remove them from the whole history.