# Combine Project VCS with single module VCS in Intellij

Tags: git, intellij-idea, version-control, multiple-repositories

I have a multi module project with 4 modules.

Currently my complete project is under VCS with all its modules, but now I want to have one of those modules at another repository.

I know it is possible to attach each module to it´s own repository, but

**is it also possible to keep my project in one repository, exclude the one module from this repo and have it in its own repository?**

The reason I want to do this is I have several other files in my project I need to have under version control, so it´s not enough for my case to only version my modules.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare your modules as [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules), you will be able to:

- keep only one parent repo (which will reference your git submodules)
- work only on one of those modules (since a git submodule is a git repo in itself)

You can [create a submodule from an existing subfolder, with its history](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18129693/6309).