# Add folder into existed git folder and make it become submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

First, my question is different from
[Create a submodule repository from a folder and keep its git commit history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17413493/create-a-submodule-repository-from-a-folder-and-keep-its-git-commit-history) .

Suppose I have git folder, let's say `~/GITA`.
I want to move a folder `~/Folder1` into it. (`~/GITA/Folder1`).
Then in the folder (`~/GITA/Folder1`), change it into submodule.
And then push it  (submodule `~/GITA/Folder1`) to the new created server
repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it in a different way:

1. Create a new repository and add the code from `Folder1` to it.
2. Now add this repository as submodule under the `GITA` project.

Now you should have 2 project in which the `Folder1` is a submodule of the the `GITA`project.

Comment: That's a good thought, `localA->remote->localB`. So there are no direct way, such as `git submodule init;git submodule remote add`?

Comment: upi have to add init & update the submodule. 3 commands and that's it.

Comment: Excuse me, what's the meaning of "upi"? And you say 3 commands is about the former way (`localA->remote->localB`) or about the latter possible way (`git submodule init;git submodule remote add`). Thank you very much

Comment: Typo - should be you. sorry