# Make git-filter-branch on all branches

Tags: git-filter-branch, git-rewrite-history

We're doing a conversion from cvs/bugzilla to git/Stash/Jira.  I'm testing using `git filter-branch` to rewrite bugzilla bug #s in the commit messages with jira issue IDs.  This works except it only affected master and not any branches.  I used `-- --all` but didn't have any branches checked out.  Is that necessary?  Exact command follows:

```
git filter-branch -f --msg-filter 'ruby -S gitBugzillaToJira.sh' --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Note - The `gitBugzillatoJira.sh` ruby script does the work to swap bugzilla number to the Jira issue ID.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm the author of The BFG, which will offer commit message rewriting in its next release. Out of interest, how many distinct issue ids do you have to rewrite?

Comment: ~10k issues.  I've read about BFG!  Even saw the video comparing BFG (on a Pi) and filter-branch. :-)  I hadn't looked at it more because I had the filter-branch working (or so I thought) and now realized this issue...

Comment: @RobertoTyley Was this feature ever included in the BFG repo cleaner? I just used version 1.12.16 and I was unable to spot an option that allows changing commit messages.

Answer (score 1):

Your `git-filter-branch` incantation looks correct, it should be updating all refs that are in the local copy of your repo.

Here's a very similar demo, showing this working correctly, as expected :

```
$ git clone https://github.com/defunkt/github-gem.git
$ cd github-gem/
$ git filter-branch -f --msg-filter 'sed "s/e/E/g"' --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

...you'll see output like this coming back from `git-filter-branch`, indicating that it's updated **all** branches and tags (without you having to do a `git checkout` on them):

```
Rewrite 8ef0c3087d2e5d1f6fe328c06974d787b47df423 (436/436)
Ref 'refs/heads/master' was rewritten
Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master' was rewritten
Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/fallthrough' was rewritten
Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/gist' was rewritten
Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/keithpitt-ruby-1.9-update' was rewritten
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master' is unchanged
Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/organizations' was rewritten
Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/upload' was rewritten
Ref 'refs/tags/REL-0.4.2' was rewritten
```

What output do you get from this part of your `git filter-branch` run?

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  I voted your answer up for being helpful.  As evidenced below I now realize it wasn't git filter-branch that was the problem after all.  It was my git-push incantation!

Answer (score 0):

[image: User Error!]

Like the image says, it was case of user error!  After getting 3rd party confirmation my git-filter-branch should work I realized I only had done `git push` so only locally checked out branches were pushed.  Looks like I should `git push --all` to update all refs.  Now, I need to figure out why I'm getting 3 references to master along with my other branches:

```
* [new branch]      refs/original/refs/heads/master -> refs/original/refs/heads/master
* [new branch]      refs/original/refs/remotes/origin/master -> refs/original/refs/remotes/origin/master
* [new branch]      origin/master -> origin/master
```

Comment: I shoulda searched SO, first.  From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654822/remove-refs-original-heads-master-from-git-repo-after-filter-branch-tree-filte refs/original/* is the back up copy that I read about with refs/heads/master being the head pointer to my local master and refs/remotes/origin/master being the master branch